# Apache bonjour module and Sites folder template

Tags: apache, bonjour

I just upgraded to Lion and because I do web design, first thing I did was turning on Web Sharing to get Apache running. While checking the logs I found that the Bonjour module can't find a file and warns me about this:

```
mod_bonjour: Cannot stat template index file '/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Sites/index.html'
```

So I listed the files under that location and it seems the whole Sites folder is gone. I found out later that Mac OS X doesn't include that folder under your user account by default.

I'm still wondering how to stop this warnings. Is it safe to create a directory under this system location? I wouldn't like to do that.

I tried commenting

```
RegisterUserSite customized-users
```

under /etc/apache2/other/bonjour.conf thinking the error was due to the bonjour module trying to compare my index.html with the system template to activate my personal site but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same warning.
I did the following:

```
sudo mkdir "/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Sites/"
sudo touch "/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Sites/index.html"
```

apache now starts without the warning

Comment: I would also recommend doing the following command for proper propagation of permissions: `sudo chown -R root:wheel "/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Sites"`.